# Once the user is authenticated with AuthenticationManager.GetWebLoginClientContext is it possible to determine the user's login name?

Tags: authentication, sharepoint

After the user is authenticated with GetWebLoginClientContext, is is possible to determine the user's login name?

```
            var authManager = new AuthenticationManager();
            ClientContext cxt = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(siteUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try context.Web.CurrentUser property.

```
User user = context.Web.CurrentUser;
context.Load(user);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```